# Matching columns across matrices

Tags: r, matrix, distance, combinatorics, matching

Say I have two or more matrices. The number of rows and columns are same across matrices. But the matrices are not necessarily square.

```
Matrix1
     a        b        c
1    0.911    0.067    0.023
2    0.891    0.089    0.019
3    0.044    0.931    0.025
4    0.919    0.058    0.023

Matrix2
     a        b        c
1    0.024    0.070    0.906
2    0.020    0.090    0.891
3    0.025    0.930    0.045
4    0.024    0.058    0.918
```

Rows always sum to 1. Columns may shift position from matrix to matrix. Example above, column a in mat 1 is column c in mat2. The value will not be identical but similar.

What sort of statistical approach/algorithm can I use to align the columns across many such matrices?

The desired result would be something like below

```
Matrix1
     a        b        c
1    0.911    0.067    0.023
2    0.891    0.089    0.019
3    0.044    0.931    0.025
4    0.919    0.058    0.023

Matrix2
     c        b        b
1    0.906    0.070    0.024
2    0.891    0.090    0.020
3    0.045    0.930    0.025
4    0.918    0.058    0.024
```

That the columns are aligned. 'a' in mat1 corresponds to 'c' in mat2 and so on. In this one possible result, mat1 is the reference and mat2 was aligned to it. It doesn't matter what reference is used, as long as columns are aligned across all matrices.

I am using R if anyone wants to try something.

```
mat1 <-
 matrix(c(0.911,0.891,0.044,0.919,0.067,0.089,0.931,0.058,0.023,0.019,0.025,0.023),nrow=4)
mat2 <-
 matrix(c(0.024,0.020,0.025,0.024,0.070,0.090,0.930,0.058,0.906,0.891,0.045,0.918),nrow=4)
```

Comment: One natural way to address this would be to compute the correlations between all columns of matrix 1 and those of matrix 2 and attempt to create a bipartite matching. That reveals how much more information you ought to supply before you can hope for a good answer, such as (1) why might corresponding columns differ?  What is the mechanism or probability model for differences? (2) How important is it to match the columns completely correctly?  What would errors cost you?  (3) In your application, what would be a suitable way to quantify how close two columns are to each other?

Comment: Good points here. I was wondering about computing a distance (maybe euclidean) between column pairs between matrices. And align based on the smallest distance, next smallest and so on. This simple approach is probably not scalable computationally for many rows, columns and matrices. Also, I don't think there is one correct result. I think we are aiming for the best possible alignment.

Comment: That begs the questions of (1) exactly how should the distance be computed--you don't offer any guidance there--and (2) how one is supposed to measure "best". That information ought to be part of the question rather than proposed in the answers.

Comment: Please do not cross-post. [Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45660949/4752675) on Stack Overflow was a better choice for getting this answered.

Comment: @G5W Yes, apart from the fact that answers on SO could easily be algorithmically fine while totally inappropriate for the underlying statistical question.